# How to confine the site to open only with binding url instead of http://servername:portNo?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, iis7

I have 4 servers in a farm. A SharePoint web application hosted on port 1122, can we assessed with " http://servername:1122/ ". I have added the bindings for which site can now open " http://applicationName/ "

How to confine the site only to open with the binding url instead of with Servername:portno, even within the server and outside?

Comment: Do you configured alternative access mapping  check this https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should:
1) Delete IIS Site of the default zone pointing to http://servername:1122
2) Extend the web application into the default zone with the new URL http://application name.

Don't manually mess with Alternate access mapping or IIS binding to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here the binding url is nothing but the DNS entry mapped to an static IP. So once the DNS name is ready then you can add it to the IIS binding and to the extended web application zone of the AAM mappings. (generally no one suggest to modify the existing default zone and the IIS bindings for a variety of reasons.)

More details about the DNS records can be found at:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727018.aspx